# WinApi - ToUnicode function throws an access violation?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
LPWSTR data[256];
ToUnicode(vk_code, 0, 0, *data, 256, 0);
```

This code throws the following exception:

`Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.`

The `vk_code` value seemed to be perfectly normal at the breakpoint, and I checked with msdn to make sure my arguments were valid. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It's worth properly learning about arrays and pointers before trying to fumble with the Windows API. You're giving it an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @chris Will do, when looking into the `0xCCCCCCCC` address, it turns out to be a memory location used for debugging uninitialized values.

Comment: That's not correct. The 'address' `0xCCCCCCCC` is not meaningful at all. `0xCC` is the pattern used to initialize uninitialized variables in a debug configuration. It helps you easily spot uninitialized variables during debugging. That actual value is not interesting, though. You'd get the very same exception when passing `nullptr` in place of `*data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an uninitiated pointer to the `pwszBuff` parameter. It expects a pointer to an allocated array of characters. Change your array to use `WCHAR` elements instead of `LPWSTR` elements, and get rid of the `*` dereference operator:

```
WCHAR data[256];
int res = ToUnicode(vk_code, 0, 0, data, 256, 0);
switch (res) {
    case -1:
        // dead-key character, nothing written to data[]... 
        break;
    case 0:
        // no translation, nothing written to data[]... 
        break;
    default:
        // res # of characters written to data[]... 
        break;
}
```